# Plotting a simple bargraph in R, Error: Height must be a vector of matrix

Tags: r, bar-chart, data-visualization

This is my dataframe in R,

```
New York  8755
     Texas  7654
California  6726
   Florida  6322
```

I simply want the graph to compare the numbers in a bar stacked side by side.I have not been able to achieve that.
I am getting the error "Height must be a vector of Matrix."
Please suggest!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the command you are using to plot it? You probably want something like this - barplot(x$V2,names.arg=x$V1) where x is your data, and v1 and v2 are the names of the city and data columns.

Comment: I was using barplot(us.june)
Error in barplot.default(us.june) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix
> barplot(us.june)

Comment: so, barplot(us.june[,2],names.arg=us.june[,1]). You need to tell R which column is the data, and which is the names. The error you got is R telling you it needed only numbers to plot, but you gave it something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was working on it for quite a while! I will keep this in mind now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

R cannot tell which variable is which when you pass it an entire data.frame to plot. In this case, the error, `'height' must be a vector or a matrix` is telling you you didn't give the plot function what it wanted.

For a `barplot`, using `?barplot` will tell you what is needed:

> barplot(height, width = 1, space = NULL,
>           names.arg = NULL ....

In your case, you have a data.frame with heights in the second column, and names in the first, so you want to do:

```
barplot(data[ ,2], names.arg = data[ ,1])
```